# Parse build.prop in Linux

Tags: android, linux, parsing

I would like to parse an Android build.prop using a Linux tool, but I don't know which to use.
The lines I want to parse are the following:

```
ro.build.version.incremental=eng.yannik.20130823.034129
ro.product.name=occam
```

Now the output should be eng.yannik.20130823.034129 and it should be written to a file called version-occam (parsed from ro.product.name).txt

How do I do that or which program is the right one for that?

Comment: `grep 'ro.build.version.incremental' /build.props`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to parse this file as these values are accessible in Java using the SDK constant values :

```
Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL
Build.PRODUCT
```

More information on these values are available here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

If some values located in `build.prop` are not exposed by the SDK, you can retrieve them using the `getprop` command-line utility available in your android shell :

```
getprop # retrieves all the existing key/value pairs
getprop ro.product.name
```

For completeness, note that `getprop` uses internally the `property_get` C API which is available in the Android NDK.

More info on this point here : https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/toolbox/getprop.c.

**EDIT :**

If you are expecting to parse this file on your own, outside of an Android environment (that is the SDK and the NDK), you could

- Write a simple parser for it with a tokenizer
- Write a script shell that does it (ex : `grep ro.build.version.incremental | cut -d '=' -f 2`)
- Try to use what Android uses internally to parse this file (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/5e9a086145764d64c0f7fbce5489d820aa7fdcd4/libc/bionic/system_properties_compat.c).

Comment: Yes, but I want to parse it on my Linux machine and not on the Android device ;)

Comment: I edited my answer, but may I ask for what reason you want to parse this file outside of an Android system ?

Comment: Its for the Update Checker of ROM I'm working on. The file gets pushed on the server and the app checks if the installed ROM version is still the current one.

Comment: You could simply retrieve the value of the build version in your updater and send it in XML, JSON or whatever to your server. This is what we partly do for our Android ROM updater.

Comment: Yes, would be possible too. I'll think about it. :)